# Difference between two Time Stamps in Minutes Excluding Out of Business Hours

Tags: calculated-column-formula

I want to know if it's possible to calculate add minutes to a Created Time stamp in Only Business Hours (09:00-17:00).

Example:
16:00 - 17:30(current time) = 60 min

08:50 - 09:10(current time) = 10 min

Friday 15:00 - Monday(Next Week) 09:30 = 150 min

The column should only show the minutes between the Created Column time stamp and and the time stamp now currently.

Is it possible to use SharePoint formula to do this calculations?